# FFmpeg: Invalid data found when processing input after created a video slideshow from images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, flv

FFmpeg provides some examples of making slideshow from image(s):

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

So I 've tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 10 -framerate 24 -i '1.png' -c:v libx264 -crf 36 -vf scale=640:360 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest 2.mp4
```

It is a success generating a `MP4` file. Also there's no problem remuxing it into `FLV`.

FFmpeg gave no no error when I mux the video stream into `.h264` .

But when I tried to process this file further, ffmpeg gave me this error:

`$ffmpeg -i 2.h264
ffmpeg version 2.4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  4 2014 11:01:51 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
2.h264: Invalid data found when processing input`

(OSX 10.10.1, with binary from http://ffmpegmac.net/ )

This problem can be reproduced on another Ubuntu 12.04 x64 machine:

`# ffmpeg -i 2.h264 -c copy 2.flv 
ffmpeg version 2.3.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  3 2014 13:42:36 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 94.100 / 52. 94.100
  libavcodec     55. 71.100 / 55. 71.100
  libavformat    55. 50.100 / 55. 50.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.102 /  4. 11.102
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
2.h264: Invalid data found when processing input`

So what the problem with this file?

Comment: try to replace `'` quotes to `"`

Comment: I facing the same issue but with all formats .BTW I used compiled ffmpeg from another maching could this be the issue .

Comment: Did you find any solution?!

Comment: @SalemF I'm using compiled ffmpeg as you said, but I didn't get this error till I used RTP as input!

Comment: I found solution as I remember it was issue with some libraries . I think I miss add depends like this .
 `apt-get -y --force-yes install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev \
  libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev `   `apt-get install libx264-dev `
The copied bin ffmpeg works fine on my other machines